# Remove not increasing rows based on other columns values

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame on R and I want to remove all rows that are not increasing in my column 3. Each  row have to be higher or equal than the previous one. But my main difficulty is that the rows have to increase according other columns 1 and 2. In my example, Column3 have to increase according Column1 [A-B] and 2 [1:4]. Here, Column1 [B] have to be removed because 199>197.

PS : It is CO2 measurements corresponding to many plots and date. When the CO2 measurments is not monotonous in the time, the measurement is wrong.

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 200 |
| A | 2 | 202 |
| A | 3 | 204 |
| A | 4 | 207 |
| B | 1 | 199 |
| B | 2 | 197 |
| B | 3 | 200 |
| B | 4 | 202 |

Comment: Could you post an example of your desired output? I am a bit confused on it

Comment: I want all the 199/197/200/202 rows to be deleted because they form a series which is not increasing, it means sample B (column1) has a problem.

Comment: So everything observation from a group where the values is not increasing? So in this instance, everything from group B?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post to add more context. I tried to write a loop but it's not a succes

Comment: OK see if the  latter part of my answer below solves your issue

Comment: Yes, thank you so much ! The second option works with my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff()` to determine if a group is increasing.

```r
subset(df, ave(Column3, Column1, FUN = \(x) all(diff(x) >= 0)) == 1)

#   Column1 Column2 Column3
# 1       A       1     200
# 2       A       2     202
# 3       A       3     204
# 4       A       4     207
```

---

Its `dplyr` equivalent:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Column1) %>%
  filter(all(diff(Column3) >= 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way to go about it,  but here is an approach:

If you want *just* the observation that violates the condition removed (here, the observation with value `197` in it), try this:

```
df %>% group_by(Column1) %>% 
  mutate(del = (lag(Column3) > Column3)) %>% 
  filter(!del|is.na(del)) %>% 
  select(-del)
```

Output:

```
# Column1 Column2 Column3
# <chr>     <int>   <int>
# 1 A             1     200
# 2 A             2     202
# 3 A             3     204
# 4 A             4     207
# 5 B             1     199
# 6 B             3     200
# 7 B             4     202
```

If you want to remove all the observations from a given group where the condition is not met (here, group b)

```
df %>% group_by(Column1) %>% 
  mutate(del = any((lag(Column3) > Column3), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(!del) %>% 
  select(-del)
```

Output:

```
# Column1 Column2 Column3
# <chr>     <int>   <int>
# 1 A             1     200
# 2 A             2     202
# 3 A             3     204
# 4 A             4     207
```

Data used in this example:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Column1    Column2 Column3
A   1   200
A   2   202
A   3   204
A   4   207
B   1   199
B   2   197
B   3   200
B   4   202", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should add `na.rm = TRUE` in `any()` to avoid `NA`, so that `filter(!del|is.na(del))` can be simplified to `filter(!del)`, i.e. `df %>% group_by(Column1) %>% mutate(del = any(lag(Column3) > Column3, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% filter(!del)`

Comment: Thanks for the improvement! Ive edited it to reflect this